# discretizing viridis ggplot color scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, viridis

I have an ordered factor variable that I would like to plot using `ggplot2`. Is there any way I can use `scale_color_viridis()`, a continuous color scale, with this ordered factor without casting the factor to numeric? The straightforward

```
iris$Sepal.Width <- ordered(iris$Sepal.Width)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, color=Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_continuous()
```

doesn't work.

Comment: What's wrong with casting it to numeric? Can you please delete the same question with different title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Viridis has a `discrete = TRUE` option.

```
iris$Sepal.Width <- ordered(iris$Sepal.Width)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, color=Sepal.Width)) + 
geom_point() + 
viridis::scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Last version of {ggplot2} (dev: 2.2.1.9000) now has a viridis scale included.
You can use `scale_colour_viridis_d()` for discrete values or `scale_fill_viridis_c()` for continuous values.

In your case :

```
iris$Sepal.Width <- ordered(iris$Sepal.Width)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, color=Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_viridis_d()
```

Comment: This is now in ggplot2 stable release 3.0.0